# Why can I not concatenate the result of an SSH to another variable?

Tags: macos, bash, ssh

I'm trying to SSH into a machine as the currently logged in user. Thus:

```
#!/bin/bash

ip="[ip-redacted]"
currentuser=$(ssh -t -t macuser@$ip "stat -f '%Su' /dev/console")
echo $currentuser # prints "macuser"
echo "$currentuser" # same as above
echo "$currentuser""@$ip" # prints "@[ip-redacted]"
```

Why is it that when I print currentuser by itself it prints the correct user but when I try to append it to the ip it shows up as nothing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you use the `-t` option to `ssh`, the output contains carriage return and line feed characters at the end of each line (because that's what needs to be sent to a terminal). `$(...)` automatically removes the last `LF` character, so `$currentuser` ends with a `CR`. So it's printing the output of the `stat` command, then a `CR`, then `@$ip`. The `CR` moves the cursor to the beginning of the line, then `@$ip` overwrites the username.

The simplest solution is to leave out the `-t` option (both of them -- I don't know why you used it twice). You don't need a pseudo-tty for the command you're running.

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept your answer as soon as SO lets me. I just have one quick question - what you do need a pseudo-tty for? There's another command I'm using it in and I'm wondering if I can remove it on that command as well.

Comment: From ssh man page: "Multiple -t options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty." (not that that makes it clearer why it was done here just a reason why two might be meaningful).

Comment: @TylerHou: for example, if you try to do something like `ssh ip-redacted screen -R irc`, which would open the screen session in a pseudo tty terminal; usually, when you just log in somewhere using SSH, you get that. If you just run a simple program and collect its output, you don't.